# Best recommendation for bulk cd writing

Tags: software-rec, burning, hardware-rec, compact-disc, bulk

Mymain requirement is that i want to write bulk audio cds every week around 50-100.
Now its very difficult to write cd one by one.

What is best solution for me.

Can i put 6-7 cd writers  or more in one CPU and then burn cds simultaniously

Comment: Are you making many copies of 1 thing, or are you copying many things?

Comment: yes many copiesof one thing

Comment: use can Nero or Alcohol to do this job

Comment: how can i attach 10 cd writers with one mothboard. Any connectors which can expand ribbons and power

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to be looking at something like this [bulk CD duplicator](http://shop.cd-writer.com/catalog/stordigital-copytower-5-20x-dvd-40x-cd-premium-duplicator-p-19846.html) (UK site), which from the images look like they've got multiple CD/DVD burners in a tower case.

At just under £300 it's not hideously expensive and would probably save you a whole swathe of time.

There are 1 to 7 and 1 to 11 copiers available too, but these are (obviously) more expensive.

I would assume that there are sites that serve Australia and that the cost wouldn't be too different. Do a search for "bulk CD [DVD] writer Australia".

I'm also assuming that these things come with the necessary software too.

Comment: i live in australia so can't use that.
I can easily get old cd writer for about 10$. Is it possible to make them write cds at once using computer software

Comment: I agree with ChrisF.  I once worked at a company that produced small quantities of software.  We bought a bulk duplicator with a printer.  Then we bought CD-Rs with a printable finish on the top.  Version release day was: put a stack of 50-75 blank CDs on the feed spindle, open the program, pick the image for the label, and the ISO for the CD, enter the number of copies and hit GO.  Come back in a few hours and there'd be a stack of complete CDs on the Output Spindle.  Besides the robot arm to load the disks from the spindle to printer to drive to spindle was cool.

Answer (score 1):

If the optical drives (and your motherboard) work with S-ATA you can probably attach quite a few more, but then you need an up-to-date computer to do so.

Do note that if you write at high speeds, you're hard drive has to be able to keep it supplied with data. So if your computer can't keep up with the data streams, you'll end up with burning 5 disks at much lower speeds with a overall slower burning time...

Still I recommend you try and look for an alternative to ChrisF's solution: a bulk disk duplicator.

Comment: I guess if he's burning the same data to each CD, the hard disk is not the problem, since the data should be in the file system cache after first read (provided the system has enough RAM, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I will admit they are a little expensive ($1300 USD), but a automated duplicators like this [one](http://www.discmakers.com/duplicators/automated/bravoSE.asp) is the way to go. I've used one for years and they are great. drop in a stack of blank CD or DVDs, select the data set or image, enter the quantity and go. I often let them run over night. The system we have will hold up to 50 disks. The inkjet printer is not the highest quality, but it does OK.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that the main pain in doing the duplication would be the inserting / removing the disks from the drive; even the free software on my Windows machine has a wee box asking how many copies of a disk I want to burn and although it will only write to a single drive, I can open more than one copy of the program.

If you are going to stick a bunch of cd writers into your own PC then you are probably going to need some extra PATA/SATA ports in which to plug them, [add in controller cards are available](http://www.cableuniverse.co.uk/catalog/2_port-sata_pci-host-card.html) if you have free PCI slots, and may be a beefier power supply. If the drives are not writing in sync, then each one will have to be fed data at a reasonable rate. How many simultaneous drives you can write to reliably will probably only be found out by trial and error.

In any case, you will soon get very fed up with juggling the CDs in all those drives.

[Here's](http://www.i-tech.com.au/products/34770_CAPAX_11_Disc_SATA_Duplicator_13_Bay.aspx) an Australian site selling duplicators.

If you want to do it yourself, you caould always [build yourself a robot](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/tech/changer.html).

Answer (score 0):

A project at SourceForge looks like it might do what you want, although it also looks like the installation is a little difficult. I have not tried it.
A description is available at http://turbojet.sourceforge.net/ and the files can be downloaded from the project page at sourceforge.net/projects/turbojet/.

Hope this helps...